# Update tableview content frame origin

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am changing the y origin of a UIView in the first visible cell on the viewdidscroll event.

I update the position of the cell's content at every scroll so that it doesn't visually move with the cell.

When a previous cell is not visible anymore(scroll down), I cannot see the view anymore if I scroll up.

My question : How does scrolling affect the frame the of the views inside the cells ? How can I fix my problem ? (Will post code soon)

Comment: Cells get reused. When a cell scrolls off the screen it is reused for another cell scrolling into view.

Comment: Aaahh okey I see ! I can't believe I didn't think about it thankyou ! You can post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells get reused. When a cell scrolls off the screen it is reused for another cell scrolling into view. So you need to reset any views of the cell when it get reused.

If you have a custom cell, the `prepareForReuse` method should be overridden to reset any appropriate state.